# Conditional columns to row

Tags: r, shell, perl, transpose

I have the following table with more than 30,000 lines

```
1
1   ne  A
1   en  B
1   hi  C
2
2   ne  D
2   ew  E
2   en  F
2   hi  G
3
3   en  H
3   ne  I
3   ew  J
```

The result I'm trying to get is:

```
    en  ew  hi  ne
1   B       C   A
2   F   E   G   D
3   H   J       I
```

Can any body help me?

Comment: I fixed your formatting (and removed the arbitrary-seeming "arrays" tag).   Please check.  Can you show what you have tried in order to solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for formatting the text.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is called normalization. what tools/technology you are using to achive this?

Comment: I will be trying R or Perl script to achieve this.

Comment: Great! That solved my problem in a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your table is called `df` and the columns of your table are named `X1`, `X2`, `X3` try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  spread(X2, X3)
```

Comment: This works as well. Thanks you very much.